# Tqdm making a progress bar for each loop instead of having a single bar being updated for each loop

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar, tqdm

I'm making some maps based of a csv file and since it's 200+ rows, I want to put a progress bar. I put my for loop inside the `with tqdm(range(len(index))) as pbar:` but it shows a progress bar every 2 loops instead of having a single progress bar.

```
with tqdm(range(len(index))) as pbar: 
    for i in csv():
        #make map
        for i in range(1):
            pbar.update(1)
```

The result is this

[image]
[image]
...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To keep it from making new progress bars, use `tqdm( range(len(index)), position=0 )`. In general you can `import trange` as well/instead and use `trange(len(index),position=0)` as a shortcut for tqdm(range()).

I'm not sure what csv() returns, but you can probably simplify your entire block of code and let tqdm update automatically.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(len(index))):
    #make map
```

Answer (score 1):

The plotting/printing statements that you are using (I see that in between the progress bars there are some pictures) are basically writing a "\n" character at the end of each line, so when you call again `pbar.update(1)` tqdm has to print another progress bar which will have a "\r" at the end of the line, putting the head of the writer at the beginning of the line each time.

Remove all the plot/print statements and you should be ready to go.

Comment: This works. If I save each map, the progress bar works. But if I show each map (instead of saving), the problem persists. Thanks!